# Map fragment not zooming in on current user anymore (working on my friends emulator but not mine)

Tags: java, android

I have a map fragment that is meant to zoom in on the users current location after the user starts the application. It worked perfectly earlier today. A friend of mine did a nav bar and I checked out the new branch with the working nav bar. After checking out the branch, the map still worked, but I could not set the type of landmarks I would like to show. I then deleted the AVD and created a new one. After doing so, the map stopped zooming in on the current user location. And when I tried to set a landmark type, I was hit with this error:

"E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted"

The application still works perfectly on my friends side but not on mine. Any help will be appreciated.

XML:

```
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    tools:context=".LandinPage">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            layout="@layout/main_toolbar"/>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/mapfragment"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <include
            layout="@layout/main_nav_drawer"/>
    </RelativeLayout>



    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spType"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="550dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="130dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="600dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:text="SET"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mapfragment" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Java: This is my onMapReady that was working earlier

````
  package com.example.final_opsc_task2;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class LandinPage extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    Spinner spType;
    Button btnSet;
    GoogleMap map;
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    double currentLat = 0, currentLong = 0;
    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment;

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_landin_page);

        spType = findViewById(R.id.spType);
        btnSet = findViewById(R.id.btnSet);
        supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment);
        String[] PlaceName = {"bank", "diner", "hotel", "beach"};
        String[] TypeOfPlace = {"Bank", "Diner", "Hotel", "Beach"};

        spType.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(LandinPage.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, TypeOfPlace));

        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(LandinPage.this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            getCurrentLocation();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LandinPage.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 44);
        }


        btnSet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                int i = spType.getSelectedItemPosition();

                String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json" +
                        "?location=" + currentLat + "," + currentLong +
                        "&radius=5000" +
                        "&types=" + TypeOfPlace[i] +
                        "&sensor=true" +
                        "&key=" + getResources().getString(R.string.google_map_key);

                new PlaceTask().execute(url);
            }
        });

        //assign variable
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    }

    public void ClickMenu(View view)
    {
        //Open drawer
        openDrawer(drawerLayout);
    }

    public static void openDrawer(DrawerLayout drawerLayout)
    {
        //Open drawer layout
        drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    
    public void ClickLogo(View view)
    {
        //close drawer
        closeDrawer(drawerLayout);
    }

    public static void closeDrawer(DrawerLayout drawerLayout)
    {
        //Close drawer layout
        //Check condition
        if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
        {
            //Close drawer
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    }

    public void ClickHome(View view)
    {
        //Recreate activity
        recreate();
    }
    
    public void ClickGoals(View view)
    {
        //Redirect activity to goals
        redirectActivity(this,Goals.class);
    }

    public void ClickFavourites(View view)
    {
        //Redirect activity to favourites
        redirectActivity(this,FavouritePage.class);
    }

    public void ClickSettings(View view)
    {
        //Redirect activity to settings
        redirectActivity(this,AccountSettings.class);
    }

    public void ClickLogout(View view)
    {
        //Close app
        logout(this);
    }

    public static void logout(Activity activity)
    {
        //Initialise alert dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        //set title
        builder.setTitle("Log out");
        //set message
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to log out?");
        //yes button
        builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //finish activity
                activity.finishAffinity();
                //exit app
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        //no button
        builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //dismiss dialog
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        //show dialog
        builder.show();
    }

    public static void redirectActivity(Activity activity, Class aClass)
    {
        //Initialise intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity,aClass);
        //Set flag
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        //Start activity
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //close drawer
        closeDrawer(drawerLayout);
    }

    private void getCurrentLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Task<Location> task = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if(location != null) {
                    currentLat = location.getLatitude();
                    currentLong = location.getLongitude();

                    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
                            map = googleMap;

                            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                                    new LatLng(currentLat,currentLong), 10
                            ));

                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 44) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                getCurrentLocation();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;

        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(currentLat,currentLong), 15
        ));
    }


    private class PlaceTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String data = null;
            try {
                data = downloadUrl(strings[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            new ParserTask().execute(s);
        }
    }
    private String downloadUrl(String string) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(string);

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.connect();

        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            builder.append(line);
        }
        String data = builder.toString();
        reader.close();

        return data;
    }

    private class ParserTask  extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,List<HashMap<String,String>>> {
        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(String... strings) {

            JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();

            List<HashMap<String,String>> mapList = null;
            JSONObject object = null ;
            try {
                 object = new JSONObject(strings[0]);
                 mapList = jsonParser.parseResult(object);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mapList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> hashMaps) {
           // map.clear();

            for (int i=0; i<hashMaps.size();i++) {
                HashMap<String,String> hashMapList = hashMaps.get(i);

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(hashMapList.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble((hashMapList.get("lng")));
                String name = hashMapList.get("name");
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat,lng);

                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
                options.position(latLng);

                options.title(name);

                map.addMarker(options);

            }
        }
    }
} ```
````

Comment: provide your full code please

Comment: why is your map fragment inside of a DrawerLayout?, make sure you provided full xml code

Comment: Solved. A fresh install of android studio did the trick.